# How to set specific workspace folder for jenkins multibranch pipeline projects

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have an external tool that should be called as build-step in one of my jenkins jobs. Unfortunately, this tool has some issues with quoting commands to avoid problems with whitespaces in the path that is called from.

Jenkins is installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins`. Hence I'm having trouble with jenkins calling the external tool.

What I tried is to set "Workspace Root Directory" in Jenkins->configuration to `C:\jenkins_workspace` in order to avoid any whitespaces. This works for Freestyle Projects but my Multibranch Pipeline Project is still checked out and built under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace`.

One solution would be to move the whole jenkins installation to e.g. `C:\jenkins`. This I would like to avoid. Is there a proper way to just tell Jenkins Pipeline jobs to use the "Workspace Root Directory" as well?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Thanks Olivier for the improvements..

Answer (score 52, accepted):

the `ws` instruction sets the workspace for the commands inside it. for declarative pipelines, it's like this:

```
ws("C:\jenkins") {
  echo "awesome commands here instead of echo"
}
```

You can also call a script to build the customWorkspace to use:

```
# if the current branch is master, this helpfully sets your workspace to /tmp/ma
partOfBranch = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'echo $BRANCH_NAME | sed -e "s/ster//g"')
path = "/tmp/${partOfBranch}"
sh "mkdir ${path}"
ws(path) {
  sh "pwd"
}
```

you can also set it globally by using the `agent` block (generally at the top of the `pipeline` block), by applying it to a `node` at that level:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    node {
      label 'my-defined-label'
      customWorkspace '/some/other/path'
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Example Build') {
      steps {
        sh 'mvn -B clean verify'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Another `node` instruction later on might override it. Search for `customWorkspace` at https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/. You can also it use it with the `docker` and `dockerfile` instructions.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, this works for all commands in the body of ws. Is there a way to set workspace for all stages in a jenkins pipeline file?
Otherwise I'd have to repeat ws("C:\jenkins" in every stage...

Comment: @burnettk do you know if there is a way to call a script to build the customWorkspace to use? I would like to extract the name of the regex based on the name of the branch.

Comment: edited to include answer for this question. don't be afraid to submit a new question next time. :)

Comment: The "customWorkspace" instruction doesn't work in scripted pipeline

Answer (score 3):

Try this syntax instead:

```
pipeline {
    agent { 
        label {
            label 'EB_TEST_SEL'
            customWorkspace "/home/jenkins/workspace/ReleaseBuild/${BUILD_NUMBER}/"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: according to [the docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#common-options), it should be `node` instead of `label` within the `agent` section.