# Jenkinsfile and multiple nodes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have some code that needs running (build, test, and packages in actuality but for example just running `tox`) on different OSes. Currently my `Jenkinsfile` looks like thus:

```
pipeline {

    // Where to run stuff.
    agent { 
        node {
            label 'CentOS7' 
            customWorkspace '/home/build/jenkins/workspace/pipelines/ook'
        }
    }

    // What to run goes here.
    stages {
        stage('Tox') {
            steps {
                sh 'tox -v --recreate' 
            }
        }
    }

    // Clean up after ourselves.
    post {
        failure {
            mail subject: "\u2639 ${env.JOB_NAME} (${env.BUILD_NUMBER}) has failed",
                    body: """Build ${env.BUILD_URL} is failing!
    Somebody should do something about that\u2026""",
                          to: "devs@example.com",
                     replyTo: "devs@example.com",
                        from: 'jenkins@example.com'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The middle bit, I want to run on two different `nodes`: one for OS 1 and one for OS 2.

*How do I do that?*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure, you would want to label your slave nodes somehow. I didn't look up what tox is, but maybe like 'os_linux' and 'os_mac', and then you can use the `node` step in your Jenkinsfile to run some commands in the context of each slave. So your Tox stage might look like:

```
stage('Tox') {
  steps {
    node('os_linux') {
      sh 'tox -v --recreate' 
    }
    node('os_mac') {
      sh 'tox -v --recreate' 
    }
  }
}
```

This will run the tasks in serial, and Jenkinsfile syntax also supports doing those two tox commands in parallel on different nodes. Use the "Pipeline Syntax" link in the left nav of your Jenkins UI (only on pipeline jobs) to play around with `node` and `parallel`. Rock on.

Comment: Any idea how to define `customWorkspace` in that case?

Comment: Also, I should [probably read the awful documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-multiple-agents) in more details… ☹

Comment: [Tox aims to automate and standardize testing in Python. It is part of a larger vision of easing the packaging, testing and release process of Python software.](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation or an example? Thanks.

Comment: yes! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627358/how-to-set-specific-worspace-folder-for-jenkins-multibranch-pipeline-projects/43633389#43633389