# Jenkins Pipeline execute same step on multiple nodes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I have below code which is executing fine on 1 node - Server1:

```
pipeline {
agent {
    node {
        label 'Server1'
        }
    }

stages {
        stage('Stage1') {
            steps {
                callStage1()
            }
        }

        stage('Stage2') {
            steps {
                callStage2()
            }
        }
    }
}

def callStage1()
{
   sh ''' #shell script
   '''
}

def callStage2()
{
   sh ''' #shell script
   '''
}
```

I want to execute Stage 1 on Server1 only and Stage2 on 3 nodes serially - Server1,Server2,Server3.
How can this be achieved?

Comment: Have you tried [`agent`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent) at stage level?

Comment: Please refer to the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43766420/7105445)