# When do the jenkins workspaces get preserved?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a bunch of pipeline jobs, yet when executed, workspaces of some get preserved, some are deleted. How does jenkins make these decisions?

Based on my findings so far:

1. All jobs executed on nodes will have their workspace persisted, e.g. `/home/ec2-user/workspaces/some-job`
2. Some works on master keep their workspaces but some others' workspaces disappear after the job has finished. For example, after my build job succeeded, if I `ssh` in I can see the its workspace directory; but all my e2e jobs have no workspace.

Note I didn't use any of `clearWs`, `deleteDir` etc in my pipelines.

By the way, the reason I'm looking into workspaces is the disk usage keeps increasing and I want to cleanup. I thought the workspace is overwritten each time a job runs, but yet I get the 'Disk space is too low' warning several times.

Comment: If I remember correctly every branch gets its on workspace-folder so 5 branches means 5x the project on your storage. Jenkins does not delete this workspace by itself.

Comment: @JustAProgrammer Thanks for pointing out, but my project only has a master branch now.

Comment: You can also check in the job's configuration. if in the "post-build actions" you have kept "delete workspace when the build is done" step.

Comment: @mkemmerz "Jenkins does not delete this workspace by itself".  So, do you mean that jenkins ships with functionality that will eventually flood your disk space? Unless you tidy them up manually, or use a plugin

Comment: @DavidLavender Yes, this is correct. Your workspace will simply grow until it is full. Jenkins provides `CleanWs()` (Workspace Cleanup Plugin) for example which helps you to prevent this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is creating a new workspace for  every build job (= run) per default. You can see that in the path of the ws in your console log: /here/is/the/ws@buildnumber. If you dont want to have that behavior you can set it to an path which is for instance for every repo the same: [How to set specific workspace folder for jenkins multibranch pipeline projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627358/how-to-set-specific-workspace-folder-for-jenkins-multibranch-pipeline-projects#43633389)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some of your jobs don't get executed on the Jenkins Master, but on some connected Node (via an `agent` directive within your Jenkinsfile or Pipeline description). If that's the case you won't see a build directory inside the workspace for this Job on the Jenkins master, but on the connected Node.
You would only get the build results (like artifacts, reports, etc.) under `/<JENKINS_HOME>/jobs/My_Job/` on the Master.

Remember that you could trigger a Jenkins build on a node also indirectly if you, for example, run the build within a Dockerfile and have configured (within Jenkins configuration) a specific node label for execution of Docker builds.